# How is this paper published in Physical Review E not claiming to break the second law of thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, graphene, brownian-motion

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.09083) has the following abstract:

> We theoretically consider a graphene ripple as a Brownian particle coupled to an energy storage circuit. When circuit and particle are at the same temperature, the second law forbids harvesting energy from the thermal motion of the Brownian particle, even if the circuit contains a rectifying diode. However, when the circuit contains a junction followed by two diodes wired in opposition, the approach to equilibrium may become ultraslow. Detailed balance is temporarily broken as current flows between the two diodes and charges storage capacitors. The energy harvested by each capacitor comes from the thermal bath of the diodes while the system obeys the first and second laws of thermodynamics.

Can someone explain the importance/meaning of the claimed result for a layperson? In particular, how does this *not* violate the second law, if it's "thermodynamic fluctuations" being harvested?